# How do I check if an order was reordered

Tags: magento-1

I want to check if an order was reordered, in other words if the reorder button was pressed from adminpanel.

I have the collection of orders:

```
foreach ($collection as $order) {
     // if $order->checkIfItWasReordered(){
     // do smth 
     //} 
}
```

Is there any function or smth to check if an order was reordered ? Thx

Answer (score 2):

There is a relation between order and re-order called `relation_parent_id`. You can check it by using following code.

```
if($order->getRelationParentId()){
  // do stuff
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be it and I didn't check it yet but when order is reordered from backend this column remains intact. So this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do customization for that. You could add a flag in order table and could set that value when it a case of reorder.